# Normal Probability Distribution compared to Normal Cumulative Probability Distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

This is likely a duplicate, but can't find it on MSE.

Let's say I have a normally distributed population with $\mu=2.75$ and $\sigma=0.25$.  If $x$ is a value in the population of interest, using the normal probability distribution function I find that

$$P(x=3)\approx 0.96788,$$

and using the normal cumulative probability distribution I find that

$$P(x\le3)\approx 0.84134.$$

At first glance, it seems counterintuitive that a value being equal to 3 is more likely to be chosen from the population than a value being less than or equal to 3.

I do not have a strong statistics background, but I understand that the normal probability density curve is continuous (while the population must be finite and hence discrete), and I suspect this may be the issue with this seeming paradox.

Now my question is:

> Can someone give an elementary explanation for why this occurs using simple (practical) language?

Comment: The first value is not a probability, it is a density.  No single value has a positive probability of occurring (for this distribution anyway).  The probability of $x$ being in some region is the integral of the density function over that region.

Comment: ...And actually, $P(x=3)=0$, which is less than $P(x\le3)$ since $P(x\le3)>0$.

Comment: @lulu, then what should I take the first value to mean (practically speaking in terms of the population)?  According to Wikipedia, the first value "describes the relative likelihood for this random variable to take on a given value."

Comment: think of it as a relative notion.  If the probability density is higher nearer $x_1$ than $x_2$ then your random variable has a greater chance of being near $x_1$.   Note that the density could be any (non-negative) value, doesn't have to be $≤1$.

Comment: @lulu I am surprised at that, but it makes sense in the context of **relative** likelihood.  I need to read more about what density means.  Why is the word "density" used here anyway?  A link would suffice.

Comment: It's not wrong so much as informal.  "take on" ought to read "approach" or something like that.  Here's something that seems to give a good qualitative discussion:  http://mathinsight.org/probability_density_function_idea (Caveat:  I just now found it by an online search.  Looks ok on a quick read but I didn't study it carefully).

Comment: @Did, so there is no chance of choosing a value 3 out of the population of interest?

Comment: Exactly. As there is no chance to choose any specific value. This is because the quantity of interest is *continuously distributed*. The number 0.96788 in your post is not $P(x=3)$ but the limit, when $\varepsilon\to0^+$, of $$\frac{P(3-\varepsilon\leqslant x\leqslant3+\varepsilon)}{2\varepsilon}.$$

Comment: Just to emphasize:  there is a difference between "impossible" and "probability $0$".  Say you choose a real number between $0$ and $1$ by uniformly selecting it's decimals (digits $0,\dots,9$ with equal probability).  It is impossible to get $\pi$ this way.  It is possible to get $\frac 13$ but that has probability $0$ (you need every single random selection to be $3$).

Comment: @lulu, yes this all has to do with the countability of rationals - and I realize this is all steeped in measure theory.  Thanks.

Comment: You should notice that there is a significant difference between a continuous probability distribution and a discrete probability distribution.  The Normal distribution is continuous, in which single points all have a probability of zero.  Discrete distributions, such as the Poisson, have points with non-zero probabilities.

Comment: @MitchellKaplan, I am aware of this.  Regarding that, read my answer below!

Comment: Connection to approximation of a discrete distributions by continuous distribution: $1$. If $f_X$ is monotone on $(x_0-1,x_0+1)$ then for some unit interval $I$ containing $x_0$ we have $P(x\in I)=f(x_0)$. $2$. If $|f''|\le M$ on $I=[x_0-\frac 1 2,x_0+\frac 1 2]$, then $|f(x_0)-P(x\in I)|\le \frac M {24}$ so in both cases $f(x_0)$ represents probability of belonging to a unit interval - in one case precisely, in one case approximately.

Comment: @JohnMolokach Sorry, I didn't notice you were the author of that answer.  With regard to that, I've always stayed away from trying to use the density other than by integrating it.  As regards your answer I do think that your reasoning is sound.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume upvotes validate the accuracy of the following answer:

The first value is not a probability, but a density value, $D_p$ given by

$$D_p=\frac1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}.$$

The density for a value $x=a$ should be used to compare whether a value $x_i$ is more likely to be chosen from the population if it is near (within a specified $\varepsilon$) of $a$ as opposed to some other value $b\ne a$.

In this sense, the probability is defined as an accumulation of these densities.  Since the densities are distributed on a continuous curve, the accumualtion is done by an integral so that
$$P(x_i\le a)=\int_{-\infty}^aD_p\,dx.$$

So for this question, a value near $x=3$ is more likely to be chosen from the population than say $x=2$, and values near the mean value of $x=2.75$ are most likely to be chosen (and this due to symmetry).

It should also be noted, and related to this question, that in the event the normal distribution is used to *approximate* a discrete distribution, then as the sample size $n\to\infty$, a value $x_i$ near the mean remains most likely to be chosen at random from the population, while $P(x_i)\to 0$ for all such $x_i$ in the population.

Comment: "I will assume upvotes validate the accuracy of the following answer" Upvotes on MSE? The *mathematical* accuracy? Certainly not... :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely but could it be the probability of being within 3 standard deviations of the mean ?
If you computed statistics you generated using few samples, outliers may have more weight than they should ie 1-96.8% instead of 1-99.7%.

How did you find 96.788% ?

Comment: normalpdf(3,2.75,0.25) on the TI-83, or equivalently,
$$\frac4{\sqrt{2\pi e}}.$$